# open-xchange with an active directory authentification

Tags: active-directory, ldap, open-xchange

we would like to test and hopefully switch to [open-xchange](https://www.open-xchange.com/) (from MS Exchange). We will buy it with support, but right now we are just in the testing phase, so I need your help.
The following error keeps poping up and nobody can login:

```
file: /var/log/open-xchange/open-xchange.log.0  

com.openexchange.exception.OXException: SRV-0001 Categories=TRY_AGAIN Message=
'The required service com.openexchange.authentication.AuthenticationService is temporary not available. 
Please try again later.' exceptionID=1870517054-3
```

*Here is the content from: /opt/open-xchange/etc/ldapauth.properties*

```
java.naming.provider.url=ldap://contoso.com:389/dc=contoso,dc=com
java.naming.security.authentication=simple
uidAttribute=cn # alternative  uidAttribute=sAMAccountName has also been tried
baseDN=ou=users,dc=contoso,dc=com
adsBind=true # false has also been tried
bindOnly=true # false has also been tried
ldapScope=base # subtree has also been tried
# searchFilter # is this needed?
bindDN=readOnlyAdmin,ou=admins,dc=contoso,dc=com
bindDNPassword=secret
```

The authentication ldap bundle is ACTIVE:

```
root@openexchange /o/open-xchange# sbin/listbundles |grep ldap
bundlename: com.openexchange.authentication.ldap status: ACTIVE
```

If I search the net for it, I find one or two results, with the same problem, but their solutions (e.g. https://forum.open-xchange.com/archive/index.php/t-7634.html) didn't work out for me.
I hope someone can put me in the right direction.

**System:**
 - CentOS 7
 - SELinux = disabled
 - OpenExchange is installed from http://software.open-xchange.com/products/appsuite/stable/backend/RHEL7/
- The Active Directory is Windows 2008 R2 based.

Comment: Stupid question: Did you edit the DNS entries according to your environment in ldapauth.properties? it shows contoso.com. You should edit your real domain out before posting here but did you do the entries in your working environment? aka `ldap://yourcompany.com:389/dc=yourcompany,dc=com`

Comment: That's why I used contoso. I used the correct URI for our domain. The answer implies, that the problem is not a wrong login, but a disfunctional service?!